# Importing a module from directory with spaces

Tags: python

I've searched for this on SO but to no avail.

I have a module in `"./my folder/folder"`, this has a space and im having troubles importing this in my py file see below.

```
import "my folder.folder"
```

Leads to an error.

Comment: Can't you just remove the space or replace it with an underscore?

Comment: `foo_bar_baz = __import__("foo bar.baz")` should work; check the above question.

Comment: Categorically, spaces in a file path is a bad idea. (Thanks for facilitating bad behaviour MS!). If possible, rename the file path, it’ll save you a lot of headache (generally speaking).